# Windows cmd line: calling SQL directly does not work, but typing out the entire query does

Tags: windows, cmd, psql

I am trying to call an sql file via cmd line. Using -f the command line freezes and nothing moves/is returned.

```
psql.exe -U someUsername -h localhost -d someDbName -f "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\selectNames.sql"
```

However, typing out the entire command and using -c does work completely fine.

```
psql.exe -U someUsername -h localhost -d someDbName -c "Select names from table123;"
```

How can I use -f to call the selectNames.sql file in cmd line?

Comment: Is the server running on your local machine, and does the server account have access to your user directory? The server is what would be executing the script, and if it can't get to your local C: drive and access your personal desktop folder, it can't execute the script.

Comment: @KenWhite yes the server is running. How would I check if it has access? Also, I tried running both these commands in a java class via ProcessBuilder and the same results occur except I can see instead of things getting frozen, it says "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." (this is when using -f and the path to the sql)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean whether the server was actually up and running. I aked if the server is running on the same exact computer where C:\Users\Name\Desktop is located. IOW,  are you sitting at the keyboard at the same exact computer that the server is running on? You'd check to see if the server has access by checking the account under which the server is running. If it's not your personal login that the server is using, it has no access to your own folder. From the error message, it seems pretty clear that the answer to at least one of those questions is *No*.

Comment: @KenWhite they are running on the same exact computer.